# invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

i have this error when i want to search with params and order too in list :

> ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "customers"
>
> HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "customers_contract_periods".

Here's my query in rails 4.2.1 :
Before i do this :

```
order = "CONCAT(customers.company_name, customers.last_name)"
```

and :

```
contract_periods = ContractPeriod.current
                                 .joins( :contract, :customer )
                                 .merge( Contract.search params[ :search ] )
                                 .select( 'contract_periods.*' )
                                 .where( filter_params )
                                 .reorder( order, :start_on )
```

and :

```
contract_periods = contract_periods.merge ContractPeriod.by_state params[ :by_state ] if params[ :by_state ]

contract_periods = contract_periods.paginate( page: params[ :page ],
                                          per_page: params[ :per_page ])


contracts = Contract.includes( :contract_type, :customer )
                    .where( id: contract_periods.map(&:contract_id) )

contract_types = contracts.map( &:contract_type ).uniq
customers = contracts.map( &:customer )
```

Model associations :

```
  class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base

  ## Associations
  belongs_to  :billing_address,   class_name: 'Address'
  has_many    :contacts, as: :contactable

  has_many :contracts

class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :contract_type
belongs_to :customer
has_many   :contract_periods

class ContractPeriod < ActiveRecord::Base

## Associations
belongs_to :contract
has_one    :customer,   through: :contract
```

Comment: paste model associations

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you refer any associated table in query you have to mention it as `.references(:contracts)` at the end of code.

Comment: where exactly i have to mention this?

Comment: contract_periods = ContractPeriod.current
                                 .joins( :contract, :customer )
                                 .merge( Contract.search params[ :search ] )
                                 .select( 'contract_periods.*' )
                                 .where( filter_params )
                                 .reorder( order, :start_on ).references(:contracts)